CompizConfig not working with xubuntu 24.04
Installation has no problem but nothing is working as expected. i.e. windows animations. wobbly windows, zoom, etc
The error on running ccsm:
billi@Predator-PH315-53:~$ ccsm
compizconfig - Info: Backend     : gsettings
compizconfig - Info: Integration : true
compizconfig - Info: Profile     : default

** (ccsm:47040): WARNING **: 09:10:54.225: expected enumeration type PangoWrapMode, but got GtkWrapMode instead

** (ccsm:47040): WARNING **: 09:10:54.230: expected enumeration type PangoWrapMode, but got GtkWrapMode instead

** (ccsm:47040): WARNING **: 09:10:54.235: expected enumeration type PangoWrapMode, but got GtkWrapMode instead

** (ccsm:47040): WARNING **: 09:10:54.238: expected enumeration type PangoWrapMode, but got GtkWrapMode instead


lsb_release -a
neofetch
If there is more information needed. please comment.

GTK_MODULES=gail:atk-bridge compiz --replace

This code works.
I Tried running Compiz with environment variables that might help mitigate compatibility issues
This command forces GTK to load some accessibility modules (gail and atk-bridge) that might resolve the wrapping issue.
Though I got it from ChatGPT, and when I use this in terminal, works fine. But after a Ctrl+c, keyboard crashed and I had to restart.
So I add this in startup.
Again from GPT:
Steps to Add Compiz to Startup Applications
Open the Startup Applications Preferences:
Press Alt + F2 and type startup applications or find it in your system settings under "Startup Applications."
Add a New Startup Entry:
Click the "Add" button to create a new startup item.
In the Name field, enter something like Compiz with Compatibility.
In the Command field, enter the command:
bash -c "GTK_MODULES=gail:atk-bridge compiz --replace"

Optionally, add a description in the Comment field.
Save and Close:
Click "Add" and then "Close" to save the new startup entry.

BTW, This warning still there, but compiz is now working..
** (ccsm:47040): WARNING **: 09:10:54.225: expected enumeration type PangoWrapMode, but got GtkWrapMode instead
```\

Just found this after fighting Compiz and Ubuntu Mate 24.04 since release.  I use compiz as I am visually impared, and I find their "negative" window switch to be amazing.
Anyway, I tried the above and it seems to work for the most part.  I had to put a 20 second delay in the startup config.  I still am having a few other various problems (right click on desktop not working), but I think those may be Ubuntu Mate 24.04 issues, and not compiz.

I also have a few problems, right click on the title of a window shows fewer options and many important options i.e. Always on top not there. So I had to stop using Compiz for now...
But some functionality working without setting up the GTK_MODULES like window snapping,,,

I added a second startup application command that seems to get panels and the desktop working a bit better.  I put this on a 30 second delay:  bash -c "gsettings set org.mate.background show-desktop-icons false &&gsettings set org.mate.background show-desktop-icons true && mate-panel --reset"
